# java Group by color and Summing all Properties to produce a map

Tags: java, java-stream

There  is list of widgets i want to group them by color while adding other similar properties and produce a map , something like this .

```
        class Widget {
            String colour;
            Double legs;
            Double arms;
          
        }
        
        List<Widget> widList = new ArrayList();
        Widget wid1 =  new Widget();
        wid1.setColor("Yello");
        wid1.setLeg(10);
        wid1.setArms(10);
        
        Widget wid2 =  new Widget();
        wid2.setColor("Yello");
        wid2.setLeg(20);
        wid2.setArms(30);
        
        Widget wid2 =  new Widget();
        wid2.setColor("White");
        wid2.setLeg(20);
        wid2.setArms(30);
        
        
        widgets.stream().collect(groupingBy(Widget::getColour, AllLegstotal(wid1.legs+wid2.legs) and AllArmstotal(wid1.arms+wid2.arms));
```

result should be

"Yello" : Legs(10+20) , Arms(10+30)
"White" : Legs(20) , Arms(30)

```
        widgets.stream().collect(groupingBy(Widget::getColour, Collectors.summingDouble(All Legs , All Arms));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the [`toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#i34) collector.

> `toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K> keyMapper, Function<? super T,? extends U> valueMapper, BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction)`
> Returns a Collector that accumulates elements into a Map whose keys and values are the result of applying the provided mapping functions to the input elements.

```
Map<String, Widget> result = widgets.stream().collect(
        Collectors.toMap(
            Widget::getColor, // keyMapper
            Function.identity(), // valueMapper
                (w1, w2) -> new Widget( // mergeFunction
                        w1.getColor(),
                        w1.getLegs() + w2.getLegs(),
                        w1.getArms() + w2.getArms()
                )
        )
);
```

The mergeFunction is a BinaryOperator that is used to combine the values of two elements with the same key.
The example above creates a new Widget object with the same color, but with the total number of legs and arms calculated as the sum of legs and arms of w1 and w2.

**To print out the result:**

```
result.forEach((key, value) ->
            System.out.printf("\"%s\": Legs(%.0f), Arms(%.0f)%n", key, value.getLegs(), value.getArms()));
```

Result: `"White": Legs(20), Arms(30) "Yellow": Legs(30), Arms(40)`